# Backup & recovery of multiple MySQL databases (InnoDB & MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, database, backup, database-backups

I am working on nightly and hourly backups of MySQL Databases. There are multiple MySQL databases which are either InnoDB or MyISAM (Note: Each database is either InnoDB or MyISAM for a reason). With the 2 different types I want to make sure I am grabbing everything that is needed for backup and recovery. Here is my current plan

Nightly
-mysqldump of each DB which is stored locally and remotely.

Hourly
-flush binary logs and store them locally and remotely.

Weekly
-expire binary logs older than a week.

I feel like I am grabbing everything that is needed for the MyISAM databases but I am concerned about the InnoDB databases and the log files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1) they create. Should I backup these files? Nightly? Hourly? Both? Do I really need them if I am already doing the above nightly and hourly backups?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [SQLyog -- MySQL GUI](http://www.webyog.com). It's `sja` component makes scheduling backups/synchronization pretty smooth for users, and it also available in a Community Edition.

Disclaimer:
I work for Webyog, Inc -- The publishers of SQLyog.

Edit: I'd also like to add that I find it very reliable and fail-safe and use to manage production servers.